# jom.exe error when building a Qt project on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to build my Qt project on Windows, however something called **jom.exe** prevents the build by crashing.

```
12:15:44: Running build steps for project webimage... 
12:15:44: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step. 12:15:44: Starting:
"jom.exe" qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: 
Command line failed: jom.exe 12:15:44:
The process "jom.exe" crashed. 
Error while building project webimage
(target: Desktop) When executing build step 'Make'
```

The projects build just fine on Mac and Linux and since it's been quite a while since I used Windows for anything I'm not sure on what to do here.

What I'm I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said I am unfamiliar with the windows development stack but as it turns out jom can be replaced by nmake which worked perfectly for me.